# Existence of minimal transitive model of ZF(C).

Tags: logic, set-theory

Assuming that there exists a transitive model of ZF(C). Show that there exists a minimal transitive model of ZF(C).

I am not quite sure how to approach this problem, how do I use the fact that $\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible to construct a minimal transitive model of ZF(C)?

Answer (score 2):

The fact is that you just need *a* transitive model. Here are some lemmas that will help you figure this out:

1. If $M$ is a transitive *set* model, then $L^M$ is some $L_\alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$ which is also $M\cap\rm Ord$. And $L^M$ is the smallest model of height $\alpha$.
2. If there is at least one $\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha$ is a model of $\sf ZFC$, then there is a least such $\alpha$.

Indeed, the weakly inaccessible cardinal is sufficient, but it is *far* stronger than what is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Shouldn't it say "sufficient" rather than "necessary"? I understand you meant that some strong assumption is needed, but the current phrasing may lead to confusion.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point.